# Read table from another database

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.9

Is it possible to read tables from another database using the builting CakePHP model features? I don't mean having an entirely different configuration in `DATABASE_CONFIG` but using the same host, user and password. The obvious thing:

```
class Provincia extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'shared_data.dbo.provincia';
}
```

```php
class DebugController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        /* @var $modeloProvincia Provincia */
        $modeloProvincia = ClassRegistry::init('Provincia');
        $provincias = $modeloProvincia->find('all');
    }
}
```

... triggers:

> Error: Table shared_data.dbo.provincia for model Provincia was not found in datasource default.

Comment: I dont know cakephp but in sql server you can do DBNAME.dbo.tablename. Maybe if you put DBNAME.dbo. before Provincia ?

Comment: @GuidoG That's exactly what I'm doing: `public $useTable = 'shared_data.dbo.provincia';`. What fails is some CakePHP internal stuff.

Comment: Oops I somehow missed that. Don't have an answer for you sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'll share my findings so far...*

Short answer: **you cannot**.

CakePHP magic depends heavily on information about tables and columns fetched from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views. That information is gathered in `\Sqlserver::listSources` (list of tables) and `\Sqlserver::describe` (list of columns).

While it's possible to extend the datasource driver and reimplement these methods:

```php
// Model/Datasource/CustomSqlserver.php
class CustomSqlserver extends Sqlserver {
}
```

```php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'CustomSqlserver',
        // ...
    );
}
```

... that's just the tip of the iceberg. The data structures account for two levels:

1. Schema (e.g. `dbo`)
2. Table (e.g. `users`)

They aren't designed for an extra *database* level on top. As a result, you end up needing to patch so much code that it isn't worth the effort.

---

I've also been playing with [Synonyms in SQL Server](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Synonyms/115072/). It's a more promising path because, while you still need to write `\CustomSqlserver::listSources` and `\CustomSqlserver::describe` yourself, to most (not all) effects they behave like regular tables. The main restriction though is that there can't be duplicate table names.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a new connection to `DATABASE_CONFIG`, but you could do this in the constructor so that you can inherit your `default` database credentials and just modify the `database` name:-

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->alt = $this->default;
    $this->alt['database'] = 'provincia';
}
```

Then in your `Provincia` model you can swap to the `alt` database connection:-

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->useDbConfig = 'alt';
}
```

Comment: I don't mean having an entirely different configuration in `DATABASE_CONFIG` but using the same host, user and password to access both databases at once (e.g. making joins on associated models that belong to different databases).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález as far as I am aware you will need a new configuration in  `DATABASE_CONFIG` to achieve this, but by setting it in the constructor of `DATABASE_CONFIG` you can use the existing host, user and password, and just modify the database name.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that the datasource driver does not support it at all. At `\Sqlserver::listSources`it runs `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and discards everything that doesn't show up here :(